# Classification of principal G-bundles

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, principal-bundles, representable-functor

Let $G$ be a group. We define the functor $$Bun_{G}^{*}:h(CW_{*}^{op})\rightarrow Sets_{*}$$ which takes a pointed CW complex and assigns to it the set of isomorphic classes of principal $G-$bundles over it. I have heard that we can construct a space $BG$ such that this functor can be representable (I have heard that this is a theorem by Milnor). However, I would be interested in reading a proof using the Brown representability theorem (the space $BG$ is constructed abstractly). Unfortynately, I cannot find such a result in the literature.

Comment: This is alluded to in these notes by Andy Putman (https://www3.nd.edu/~andyp/notes/BrownRepresentability.pdf) but he doesn't actually verify the hypotheses of Brown representability. I don't think it's too hard though. You need to consider "pointed" $G$-bundles ($G$-bundles together with a trivialization at the basepoint).

Comment: I have some problems of showing that this functor satisfies the properties of Brown representability. For example what is the so-called clutching construction?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan you said it is not hard. How should I do it then?